# Is there a C++ idiom for encoding so-called rate-groups (realtime computing) into a function via template magic?

Tags: c++, templates, real-time

In realtime computing, there is sometimes a concept of a rate-group. This is essentially the frequency at which a given function will be called. (e.g. RG 10 might imply executing every 10ms).

I'm wondering if there's a nice way in C++ to encode this property via template magic like so:

```
template<int rate_group> void integrate( float& some_integral, float spot_value );
```

The above function could be instantiated as follows:

```
while(true) // outer control loop
{
     // do something
     integrate<10>( error_sum, sense_feedback );
     
     for( int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++) // inner control loop
     {
          integrate<1>( error_sum_2, some_other_sense );

          // sleep 1ms
     }
}
```

The above is a toy scenario and I'm simply exploring if there's an existing idiom to do this kind of thing. I think the most important property I'd like to get from a templated approach like this is property transitivity: any function with a rategroup `rate_group`  would automatically (at compile time) resolve to the correctly specialized sub-routines that it calls. (e.g. a call from within `integrate<10>()` to some other templated function would automatically use the correct rate group).

---

**Edit:** Here's a more fleshed out description of some desireable properties.

1. probably the single biggest feature would be design time compiler warnings. Let's say a particular function `foo` is not allowed in a fast rate group, I want to ensure that any top-level function tree I call never calls `foo<10>` but is allowed to call `foo<100>`. The above really requires that there be a mechanism to instantiate templates by context. E.g. a function with `template<int rate_group>` would automatically instantiate any functions it calls with the rate group.

Examples:

```
template<int rate_group> void foo( /* ... */ );
template<int rate_group> void bar( /* ... */ );
template<int rate_group> void baz( /* ... */ );

/* impl */
void foo<10>( /* ... */ ){ std::static_assert(false, "this method cannot be called at this rate group"); };

template<int rate_group> void bar( /* ... */ )
{
    // do stuff
    foo();
}
```

Using `bar<100>` should work just fine, but trying to build `bar<10>` should result in a compile-time assertion.

The key for the above feature to function is being able to give any C++ block a contextual rate-group attribute and *by default* pass that on to any calls made within that block.

2. building on top of #1, templates would have an ordering of rate groups to disallow using slower than self rate-group functions:

   ```
   void foo<50>( /* ... */ )
   {
       bar<10>();  // OK - this is a higher rate group, and would be allowed
       bar<50>();  // OK - same rate-group
       bar<100>(); // NO - this could be a slow function - fail compilation
   }
   ```

These two features alone would already go a long way. However, both depend on the automated maintenance of the property. I'm not sure C++ allows for this level of meta-coding.

Comment: Seems like templates would work here.  What you probably want is a class template with specializations for different values of rate group, e.g. `template<Rate R> class RateGroup { };  template<> class RateGroup<Rate::RealTime> { };` etc

Comment: Can you flesh out how you envision that to be used? And in particular, how do I handle the implicit instatiation of functions with correct rate group?

Comment: Well, your question is a little vague, but what I'm understanding is that (a) rate group is a compile time notion, (b) you want to make compile time decisions based on rate group, and (c) different rate groups have different implementations.  So, you could implement explicit specializations of the template class `RateGroup`, each with differently implemented member functions.  You can then pass a `RateGroup<Rate>` around wherever (even to templated functions) and they'll all do the right thing.

Comment: Or, if you have specific ways rate groups behave differently, but they're largely similar, you could just have the main class template, and push the differences into member functions.  If you flesh out your question a bit I could be more specific.  Like show mroe details about what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited the question. (For some reason the code excerpt in the #2 isn't properly syntax highlighting.)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know idiom for your problem, but you might indeed use template to handle that.

With your restrictions:

- Inner functions should not call bigger rate.
- Possibility to limit function in given range

I would go with template class

```
template <std::size_t N>
class RateGroup
{
    friend int main(int, char**); // Give only one entry point
                                  // to create main rates.
 
    Rate() = default;
public:
    Rate(const& Rate) = default;

    template <std::size_t N2>
    RateGroup<N2> New() const requires (N2 <= N) { return {}; }
    // Or SFINAE or static_assert instead of C++20 requires.
};
```

Then you function might be

```
template<std::size_t N>
void foo(RateGroup<N> /* ... */ ) requires (N > 10);
template<std::size_t N> void bar(RateGroup<N> rateGroup,  /* ... */ )
{
    // ...
    foo(rateGroup /*, ...*/);
}

inline void baz(RateGroup<50> rateGroup /*, ... */ )
{
    bar(rateGroup); // Same one, so 50.
    bar(rateGroup.New<10>());  // OK, 10 < 50.
    bar(rateGroup.New<100>()); // Fail to compile as expected, !(100 < 50).
    bar(RateGroup<100>()); // Fail to compile: constructor is restricted to allowed functions

}
```

You can so have fixed `RateGroup` or templated ones for your functions.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I like this new `requires` keyword in C++20.

Can you think of any way that the function calls could automatically infer the rate-group instead of having it be passed as a parameter?

Comment: I don't see way to have different rateGroup depending of context. You might still redeclare function with different default inside the function, but then I don't see the gain, as you have to write those, which seems even more works than my proposed solution.

Comment: It's more about inferring the rate group based on context instead of explicitly passing it as a parameter. It's very possible this is not doable in C++ as it currently stands, but I'd like to see if it can be done. The key is being able to lexically scope the default value `N` in `template<std::size_t N=>` so that instantiating such a template defaults to the inner most scope we are in.